# saving multiple arrays to database asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am an intern and i don't get the guidance i need at my internship so i'm asking it here.

```
string sql;                

sql = "INSERT INTO Uzk.Talen (Kantoor, Taal, Spreken, Lezen, Schrijven, Talen_op_werknemerID) VALUES ";
sql += "('" + 1 + "', ";
sql += "('" + languageMatches + "', ";
sql += "('" + languageMatches + "', ";
sql += "('" + languageMatches + "', ";
sql += "('" + languageMatches + "', ";
sql += "'" + knowhowMatches + "', ";
sql += "'" + werknemerId + "')";

SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
Conn.Open();
SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Conn);
int aantal = Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Conn.Close();
```

I have two arrays called languageMatches and knowhowMatches. my code has to be able to loop the sql insert query and with every loop it has to insert the first value of both languageMatches and knowhowMatches. the second loop it has to insert the second values of both languageMatches and knowhowMatches and so on. how could i do this? thanks in advance

Comment: Used `tring.Join(",", arrayvalue);` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Do you want a different record for each of the entries in your arrays?

Comment: @Steve yes, for each entry i want it to be in a new row

Comment: Learn about paramatised queries **now**. Your code is wide open to SQL injection. Also please show a samples of your arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can pass all your entries in a local datatable and then using SqlBulkCopy to add everything to the destination table on Sql Server.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Kantoor", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Taal", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Spreken", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Lezen", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Schrijven", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Talen_op_werknemerID", typeof(string)));
for(int x = 0; x < languageMatches.Length; x++)
{
    string lang = languageMatches[x];
    string known = knowhowMatches[x];
    dt.Rows.Add(new string[] { "1", lang, lang, lang, known, werknemerId });
}
using(SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
{
    Conn.Open();
    using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(Conn))
    {   
        bc.DestinationTableName = "Talen";
        bc.WriteToServer(dt);
    );
}
```

Consider however that I have prepared a datatable with all string fields. This seems not correct in particular for the first and last field. If the DataTable in memory is different from the actual *Talen* table on the database you should change the definition above with the proper datatype (int, etc) and then provide the Rows.Add method with the appropriate datatype (int if the target column is an int and so on). Also I am not sure about the number of columns that receives the value for the language, you add 4 time the same value but the columns appears to be just three.

Of course the two arrays *languageMatches* and *knowhowMatches* should have the same number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Table Valued Paramenter feature in SQL, then it will insert very fast